# How to update Kotlin.Runtime in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Windows 10, Android Studio 3.0.1.  Just fired it up and got the "there's a new version available, update?".  I updated.  Now I get "Outdated Kotlin.Runtime. 
 Version of Kotlin runtime is outdated in several libraries" followed by a long URL.

So I need to update the Kotlin Runtime.  How do I do that?

Comment: are you using gradle? then updating the version in the build script should do the trick

Comment: 90% sure I'm using gradle.  Which build script, and which version?  New to Android studio and kotlin, but 40 years programming experience.

Comment: There should be a build.gradle file in your project root, there will be a Kotlin version specified

Comment: build.gradle had version 1.2.10, so I bumped it to 11.  A.S. gave an error message mentioning 1.2.10-release-109, so I changed it to that.  Still get an error.  What do I change the version to?

Comment: Let me re-phrase that.  How do I find out what version to use?

Comment: I’d use the latest: 1.2.21

Comment: Right answer turned out to be 1.1.51.  Found by seeing what was in the Android Studio kotlin directory.  There has to be a better way....

Answer (score 62):

You can update and install new Kotlin plugin from Android Studio itself. See
[image: screenshot from Android Studio]

Comment: To be more verbose. You can find these options under Android Studio File>Settings

Answer (score 8):

Open the "root" build.gradle of your project. At the very beginning you should find something like this:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

change te second line to looks like:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
```

How you should know exactly to which version to update the Kotlin runtime? Easy, take a look to the Event Log in Android Studio, the Kotlin plugin will complain there:
[image: Event Log message]

Comment: I did that but it keep showing, only when open project :
Outdated Kotlin Runtime
    Your version of Kotlin runtime in 'Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.0@jar' library is 1.2.0-release-90 (1.2.0), while plugin version is 1.2.30-release-Studio3.1-1.

Comment: Try this:
*./gradlew cleanBuildCache*
After that it should be fixed, if you've put
*ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30"*

Answer (score 6):

In latest version of android studio it is even easier:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Finally restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 4):

After version 3 of Android Studio you don't need the Kotlin plugin, just uncheck it. The Kotlin version will look after itself, via a metadependency variable.

Comment: What do you mean "uncheck" it.  What does your build.gradle file look like?

Comment: didnt work for me - after unchecking and restarting - the compiler couldnt even start

Comment: This corrupted my Android Studio (4.1.2) and forced reinstall from scratch :( To be fair, I was warned there were plugins dependent on it, but I thought I'd be able to just re-enable it if there was troubles.