# Jetpack Compose on Kotlin 1.5.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've updated to Kotlin 1.5 last week, and after yesterday having seen the intention of Google to make Jetpack Compose the preferred option for designing UIs, I wanted to do some testing.

The issue is that having my project updated to Kotlin 1.5, when trying to build the project I get the following error:

```
This version (1.0.0-beta07) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.4.32 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.0 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).
```

Is Kotlin 1.5 incompatible with Jetpack Compose? After googling the issue I found the [`1.5.0-M2`](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2021/03/kotlin-1-5-0-m2-released-ensure-smooth-migration-to-kotlin-1-5-0/) release, which mentions Jetpack Compose, but not in an "incompatible" manner.

Do you have any answer to this? Should I use `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck`? In that case, may I add it directly to `android.kotlinOptions` in the module's `build.gradle` file?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1:** [I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67248455/5717211) that I should add `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` as a builder arg:

```
android {
    ...
    kotlinOptions {
        ...
        freeCompilerArgs += [
            "-P",
"plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=true"
        ]
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But it's still not compiling, I get this error from the compiler:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/ir/descriptors/WrappedSimpleFunctionDescriptor
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.buildFunction(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:842)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.irLiveLiteralGetter(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:933)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitConst(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:426)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitConst(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitConst(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrConstImpl.accept(IrConstImpl.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitCall$1$3.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:624)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitCall$1$3.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.enter(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:191)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$enter(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitCall$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:623)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitCall$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.enter(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:191)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitCall(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:612)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:199)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitCall$1$3.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:624)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitCall$1$3.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.enter(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:191)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$enter(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitCall$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:623)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitCall$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.enter(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:191)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitCall(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:612)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:199)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitBranch$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:738)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitBranch$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.enter(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:191)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitBranch(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:737)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBranch(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:255)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBranch(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBranchImpl.transform(IrWhenImpl.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrWhen.transformChildren(IrWhen.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitExpression(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitWhen(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:247)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitWhen$s1031542550(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitWhen$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:705)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitWhen$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor$siblings$1.invoke(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.siblings(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:192)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitWhen(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:704)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitWhen(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:248)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitWhen(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrWhen.accept(IrWhen.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:26)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.transformChildren(IrBody.kt:62)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitBlockBody$s1031542550(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitBlockBody$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:795)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitBlockBody$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.siblings(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:193)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitBlockBody(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:794)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:118)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.accept(IrBody.kt:54)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBody.transform(IrBody.kt:27)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFunction.transformChildren(IrFunction.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:69)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:72)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitSimpleFunction$s1031542550(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitSimpleFunction$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:654)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitSimpleFunction$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.enter(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:191)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitSimpleFunction(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:654)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrSimpleFunction.accept(IrSimpleFunction.kt:29)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.util.TransformKt.transformInPlace(transform.kt:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.transformChildren(IrClass.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:66)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitClass$s1031542550(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitClass$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:450)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitClass$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor$siblings$1.invoke(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.enter(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:96)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:131)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.siblings(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:192)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitClass(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:449)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitClass(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrClass.accept(IrClass.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.transformChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:71)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitPackageFragment(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:47)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.access$visitFile$s1031542550(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitFile$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:496)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer$visitFile$1.invoke(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:158)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.siblings(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:117)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.DurableKeyVisitor.root(DurableKeyVisitor.kt:152)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.visitFile(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:463)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFile(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.accept(IrFileImpl.kt:63)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrFile.transform(IrFile.kt:48)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrModuleFragmentImpl.transformChildren(IrModuleFragmentImpl.kt:45)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:330)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.LiveLiteralTransformer.lower(LiveLiteralTransformer.kt:169)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.ComposeIrGenerationExtension.generate(ComposeIrGenerationExtension.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$convertToIr$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory$convertToIr$1.invoke(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:116)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:91)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:140)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr$default(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:66)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:592)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:212)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:155)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:110)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:303)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:124)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:607)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1659)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.descriptors.WrappedSimpleFunctionDescriptor
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 164 more
```

Comment: here's the change to follow: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1651538

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Update**:

Thanks [@Samuel Luís](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9914488/samuel-lu%C3%ADs) for finding a Compose to Kotlin compatibility table
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

---

**Update**: `androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.0.0-beta08` is released (June 2, 2021).

From this version, the expected version of Kotlin is `1.5.10`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.0.0-beta08"
}

android {
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.5.10"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-beta08"
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

See more:

- [Compose](https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose)
- [Compose Compiler](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler)

---

Compose compiler `1.0.0-beta07` is not supporting Kotlin `1.5.0` yet.

And I found that the changes of supporting Kotlin `1.5.0` have merged, but not released yet.

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1651538

For this moment, in my opinion, you should use `1.4.3` and wait for the next version (`1.0.0:beta08` or `1.0.0`)

Comment: compose_version = '1.0.0-beta09'

Comment: Note that `kotlinCompilerVersion` [can be safely removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67005588/kotlincompilerversion-is-deprecated/67005686#67005686).  
Compose now uses the kotlin compiler defined in your `buildscript`.

Comment: As mentioned in an answer below you can update the Kotlin version in your buildscript: `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"`

Comment: Just use `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion  1.0.0`

Comment: The use of `kotlinCompilerVersions` in `composeOptions` was deprecated, after which compose just used the kotlin version defined in the project level build file. Now, even that seems to be deprecated, since as of compose 1.0.1, there is no kotlin version specified in the buildScript. How to update it now? In fact, 'where' to? I am unable to build project.

Comment: Do I need to revert my kotlin version from 1.5.21 to 1.5.10 inorder to use the latest stable version of Jetpack Compose?. Is there any other better solution?

Comment: @MARSK, I changed it in `settings.gradle` file and it's working.

Comment: Yes that's the latest way of doing it. We must change the jetbrains dependency inside `settings.gradle` file. I even had a question regarding this, I'll copy the link and/or explanation as an answer.

Comment: here's a table with the compiler's version per Kotlin's version https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

Answer (score 36):

This is what I did with latest compose version as until I write today.

**`compose_version = '1.2.0-alpha01'`**

**1)** Delete following line if exists you do not need it:
[image]

**2)** Update your Kotlin version with final version if needed how to do this -> [click this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69508440/6805392)

**3)** Finally in `build.gradle (:project)` update compose version:

```
ext {
    compose_version = '1.2.0-alpha01'
}
```

And gradle plugin:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
```

Now you should not have any warnings with latest version.

Comment: If you don't want to use an alpha version of the library 1.1.1 is also compatible with kotlin 1.6.10.  You can view the full Compose to Kotlin Compatibility Map here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

Answer (score 15):

- In the build.gradle file (project):

  Change `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0"`

  To  `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.21"`
- In the build.gradle file (app):

  ```
  composeOptions {
              kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
              kotlinCompilerVersion kotlin_version
          }
  ```

  **compose_version** will be **1.0.1**

  **kotlin_version** will be **1.5.21**

Comment: "ComposeOptions.kotlinCompilerVersion is deprecated. Compose now uses the kotlin compiler defined in your buildscript."

Answer (score 9):

**[update]** compose_version = '1.0.0' is now stable for Kotlin 1.5.10

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10"
    }
}
```

Comment: compose_version = '1.0.0-beta09' is now available for Kotlin 1.5

Comment: You are right, I got this kotlin `1.5.10` compatibility errors fixed by moving all compose dependencies to `1.0.0`, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

> This version (1.0.0-beta07) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.4.32 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.0 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!)

> this version (1.0.0-beta08) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.5.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.4.31 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don’t say I didn’t warn you!).

- The version **`1.0.0-beta07`** requires Kotlin **`1.4.32`**
- The version **`1.0.0-beta08`** requires Kotlin **`1.5.10`**

Answer (score 3):

Check out this same question here [Where to specify Kotlin Version for Compose as of Compose 1.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68690667/15880865)

As of Compose 1.0.1, and Studio BumbleBee latest update (as of now), the required version of Kotlin required by compose is 1.5.10, however the Bumblebee update does not contain the kotlin version declaration even in the `buildScript` block. Now, you must change the declared dependency in the `settings.gradle` file, which is also where the studio picks it up from. Now, please note that even if you declared the correct version in the `buildScript` block in the project level build file, the project won't compile because studio will still fetch the version from the same place.

Also, if you are having a hard time finding out which version is required by the respective version of Compose, you can make the project, and when it fails, there's an option to `run` with `scan` to see full log output, which exposes the same. Alternatively, you could just edit it in the settings make it the default, whatever.

Answer (score 2):

My problem fixed by downgrading Kotlin from `1.5.20` to `1.5.10`, and adding `kotlinCompilerVersion "1.5.10"` to `composeOptions`  in `build.gradle` file. like this:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerVersion "1.5.10"
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.0.0-rc01'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, I have missed adding the below lines.

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when trying to migrate the old project to compose. For me, the solution was to create a compose activity. This can be done by hand or you can create an empty compose activity from the gallery.

Answer (score 1):

For me modifying the project level `build.gradle` file with the required version of kotlin (which is mentioned in the error message) fixed the issue.

Eg: My error message read:

```
This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.21 which is not known to be compatible. Please fix your configuration
```

So I modified the kotlin version to `1.6.10` like below:

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
```

And my problem got solved

Answer (score 0):

i get the error like this

> e: This version (1.0.0) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin
> version 1.5.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.5.20 which
> is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or
> `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn
> you!).

and then I open the build.gradle(project) and change

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.20'
```

to this

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.10'
```

dont forget to sync and run the project. hope this work in you too!

Answer (score 0):

Faced this problem when adding a new module. The fix was adding the following to the new module:

```
buildFeatures {
  compose true
}

composeOptions {
  kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
}
```

`1.0.0-beta07` seems to be what it picks when no version is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this issue while updating Kotlin version from **1.6.10** to **1.6.20**

And fixed it update **compose_version** from **1.1.1** to **1.2.0-alpha08**

Answer (score 0):

The works with Kotlin plugin `1.6.21`:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.2.0-rc01"
    kotlinCompilerVersion "1.6.21"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Make all of (upper of this page) https://stackoverflow.com/a/69508800/13432944

**And mainly see this lines**

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.4"
}
```

[Android Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59CZy.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).