# Setting Kotlin version to 1.4.32 creates syntax errors in my Compose project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am having an issue where my Android Studio project will not build when I go to downgrade it from Kotlin version 1.5.0 -> 1.4.32. When I do this Gradle will sync with no issues but all of my Kotlin code will be red (despite it being correct) and the autocomplete feature no longer works. If I reset my Kotlin version to 1.5.0 the code shows as error free and autocomplete works as intended but the project will still not build due to it not being supported with Compose Compiler. I have tried setting kotlinOptions to ignore this fact but that also gives me build errors. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please refer to this doc: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup

Comment: Compose doesn't support 1.5.0 yet check this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67600344/jetpack-compose-on-kotlin-1-5-0

Comment: And regarding the errors I would recommend you to invalidate caches and restart AS once

Comment: @atyc I have followed the first party document but still can't build (shows Kotlin code as invalid syntax and features like auto complete do not work). I have invalidated the cache and restarted AS multiple times with no success either :( Anything just so I can continue working would be great I have been trying to resolve this for days now. I even opened a support ticket with Google.

Comment: Did you use Android Studio Arctic Fox? and try to build app from the command line by `./gradlew assembleDebug`

Comment: @atyc Yes I am running version: 
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7375522, built on May 18, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.3.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Registry: ide.instant.shutdown=false, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

I haven't tried the manual build process but I will give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not very recomended, however, it did fix my issue which appears to maybe be the same as yours.

I'm using `1.5.10` for the kotlin standard library in my `app/build.gradle` and `kotlinCompilerVersion` is set to `1.4.32`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 30

    . . .

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion composeVersion
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.4.32"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.5.10"

    . . .
}
```

But in my project's `build.gradle` I'm using `1.4.32`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        composeVersion = "1.0.0-beta07"
        kotlinVersion = "1.4.32"
        accompanistVersion = "0.10.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-beta03"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

. . .
```

Comment: This resolved my issue!! Thank you so much Josh!